# How can storybook display the full content of a component, rather than just the template?

Tags: vuejs2, storybook

My storybook version is 7.0 and vue is using 2.0, here is an example:

```html
<template><MyButton label="primay" /></template>
```

By default it only shows the template part.

I want it to show all the code, Like this:

```js
export default {
    components: { MyButton },
    methods: {
      open() {
        confirm(args)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('success');
          })
          .catch(console.log)
      }
    },
    template: '<MyButton label="primay" @onClick="open" />'
}
```

How can I implement it?